# How To Save CSV parsed data into another csv file?

Tags: python, file, csv

Please see the question below the code -

```
import csv

MY_FILE = "../data/sample_sfpd_incident_all.csv"

def parse(raw_file, delimiter):
    opened_file = open(raw_file)
    csv_data = csv.reader(opened_file, delimiter=delimiter)

    parsed_data = []
    fields = csv_data.next()
    for row in csv_data:
        parsed_data.append(dict(zip(fields, row)))
    opened_file.close()
    return parsed_data

def main():
    new_data = parse(MY_FILE, ",")
    print new_data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The question is, if I want to save this parsed data to another file in csv format, how do I do it? I tried a few things, but it kinda screwed up the code at one point.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Why did you not use `csv.DictReader()` instead? It'd have handled the fields and dictionary creation automatically for you.

Comment: Do you have to retain the dictionaries-as-rows here? Otherwise you either have to specify a field order manually, or sort the field names (which may be a different order from the input), or return the fieldnames as well as the data.

Comment: I basically have to copy the data exactly as is into another file. csv format.

Comment: Then I'd drop the `dict(zip(fields, row))` and go straight for the list rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `csv.writer()` to write rows of data to another CSV file, or use `csv.DictWriter()` to write dictionaries with row data. The latter does require that you specify fieldnames up front.

Copying across CSV rows could best be done straight when reading:

```
with open(inputfilename, 'rb') as ifh, open(outputfilename, 'wb') as ofh:
    reader = csv.reader(ifh)
    writer = csv.reader(ifh)

    writer.writerows(reader)
```

Here `writer.writerows()` takes an iterable of rows; a `reader` object happens to be an iterable, so this copies data straight across. You can add additional dialect parameters t othe `csv.reader()` and `csv.writer()` constructors to change the format; say you read with `delimiter='\t'` (tab separated) and write out the default comma-separated format.

If you want to process each row in between, use a loop:

```
for row in reader:
    # do something with row
    writer.writerow(row)
```

The `writer.writerow()` (singular) method takes one row at a time to write out.

To copy across dictionary rows, you need to specify the fields. Use a `csv.DictReader()` object to produce the dictionaries, it'll handle fieldnames from the first CSV row for you:

```
with open(inputfilename, 'rb') as ifh, open(outputfilename, 'wb') as ofh:
    reader = csv.DictReader(ifh)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(ifh, fieldnames=reader.fieldnames)

    writer.writerows(reader)
```

Here, the `fieldnames` parameter is taken straight from the `csv.DictReader().fieldnames` attribute. Again, process rows in a loop as required, same as with a regular `csv.reader()` / `csv.writer()` pair.

Comment: Thank you for such detailed answer. I am gonna implement this and come back later.